# Recurse through directories and rename/append file names based on parent dirs

Tags: vbscript

I have a directory with a bunch of subdirectories.

MAIN_DIR\

Each sub-dir is a "project name", e.g.

MAIN_DIR\BOBEVANS324

MAIN_DIR\BILLJOHNSON3

Each "project" folder contains a bunch of sub-dirs in it. Let's say I was looking for ".abc" files that all have names that make no sense without looking at the folder structure. For example,

MAIN_DIR\BOBEVANS234\SUBDIR\3904902490.abc

As you can see "3904902490.abc" doesn't make any sense outside the context of the directory tree. I'd want to rename it by appending the directory names to the filename after copying the file.

So, it would look through ALL subfolders of MAIN_DIR and try to find ".abc" files. When it finds one, it copies it over to a dest directory and renames it something like "BOBEVANS234_SUBDIR_3904902490.abc".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to look at the [FileSystemObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d6dw7aeh%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), especially the [Folder Object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1c87day3%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and it's [SubFolders](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e1dthkks%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [Name](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zawxett8%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (to create the new names) properties and the [File Object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1ft05taf%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and it's [Move Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kxtftw67%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (remember, if you move a file to a different name in the same directory, it will have the same effect as a rename).

To find the files to rename, you'll have to look for them by hand unfortunately, though it is reasonably easy as can be seen in this MS KB article (it's written for VB6 but that's very similar to VBScript): [HOW TO: Recursively Search Directories by Using FileSystemObject](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/185601)

Answer (score 0):

Here is my recursion function that i use for my scripts, You may use it as well

NOTE **You must use Recurse**, ***NOT RecurseX*** recursex is used by Recurse Function.

NOTE: If there is a LOT of subdirectories then Recursion may take a while.

The Recurse function will return an **ARRAY** containing all the folders and ***EVERY*** subfolder.

for example:

```
Dim I, SubDirectories

SubDirectories=Recurse ("MAIN_DIR")

For I=0 To UBound (SubDirectories)

WScript.Echo SubDirectories (I)

Next
```

`'##########################################
    '#                                        #
    '#             Function                   #
    '#                                        #
    '#           Recurse Function             #
    '#          by Ronnie Matthews            #
    '##########################################
    '#                                        #
    '# This will return an array of all       #
    '# Folders and subfolders (every levels)  #
    '# in a directory provided.               #
    '#                                        #
    '##########################################`

```
Function Recurse (dir)

    Dim FSO
    Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.Filesystemobject")


    If Not FSO.FolderExists (dir) Then

        Recurse=Array (Empty)
        Exit Function
    End If

    Dim RecArr, RecArrID
    RecArr=Array (dir)
    RecArrID=1
    Recurse=RecurseX (dir,RecArr,RecArrID)
    RecArr=Empty
    RecArrID=Empty



End Function

'DO NOT CALL THIS FUNCTION DIRECTLY. ONLY RECURSE
Function RecurseX (Dir,RecArr,RecArrID)



    Dim F,FSO

    Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.Filesystemobject")

    For Each F In FSO.GetFolder (dir).SubFolders
        ReDim Preserve RecArr (RecArrID)
        RecArr (RecArrID)=F.Path
        RecArrID=RecArrID+1
        If F.SubFolders.Count>=1 Then


            RecurseX=RecurseX (F.Path,RecArr,RecArrID)

        End If

    Next

    RecurseX=RecArr

End Function
```